# Plot values by date showed by a string

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I can´t find how to plot values by a string into a time chart.

Here is my data.

The input (from csv):

```
Fecha,Pais,count
"20/05/2017",Brazil,1
"20/05/2017",China,821
"20/05/2017",Czechia,31
"20/05/2017",France,1
"20/05/2017","Republic of Korea",1
"21/05/2017",Argentina,5
"21/05/2017",Australia,2
"21/05/2017",China,3043
"21/05/2017",Denmark,1
"21/05/2017",Egypt,1
...
..
.
```

I have imported al the data from the CSV with the Date, String and Integer values parsed well:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-20', '2017-05-20', '2017-05-20', '2017-05-20',
               '2017-05-20', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
['Brazil' 'China' 'Czechia' 'France' 'Republic of Korea' 'Argentina'
 'Australia' 'China' 'Denmark' 'Egypt' 'France' 'Hungary' 'Netherlands'
 'Oman' 'Republic of Korea' 'Russia' 'Slovak Republic' 'Taiwan' 'Ukraine'
 'United Arab Emirates' 'Argentina' 'Brazil' 'China' 'Czechia' 'Ecuador'
 'France' 'Germany' 'India' 'Latvia' 'Liberia' 'Pakistan' 'Peru'
 'Republic of Korea' 'Russia' 'Taiwan' 'Ukraine']
['1' '821' '31' '1' '1' '5' '2' '3043' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1'
 '3' '48' '1' '2' '1' '3759' '79' '2' '1' '3' '1' '192' '1' '1' '1' '1' '2'
 '1' '1']
```

In fact I have the plot:

[image: see plot figure]

but, I can´t join the values by the same country, plotting the history by each in the date that contains data.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter
import datetime


locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)

date, country, count = np.loadtxt("72hcountcountry.csv",
                                  delimiter=',',
                                  unpack=True,
                                  dtype='string',
                                  skiprows=1)

date = np.char.replace (date, '"', '')
country = np.char.replace (country, '"', '')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

print date2
print country 
print count

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(date2, count)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.autoscale_view()

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

**How can I separate each country plotting with line each date with data?**

Comment: Also, could I suggest that you change the title of the question to one more related to your actual question at the end? Something similar to "Plot data from file separated by (string) value in one of the columns" could be better, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks so much @Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can achieve it using the Pandas library: you need to read the input data into a `DataFrame` (it should handle correctly the date format), and then make use of the `groupby` method (see doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)).

A simple example for the case of your csv file is here (you'll probably want to additionally change the format of ticks, etc.):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

infile = "foo.csv"

# Read in the file to a Pandas 'DataFrame'
df = pd.read_csv(infile)

# Group the different entries by the content of the
# Country/Pais column
dfg = df.groupby('Pais')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Loop over group names (country names),
# and plot each one separately (assigning the appropriate label)
for country in dfg.groups.keys():
    thisdf = dfg.get_group(country)
    ax.plot_date(thisdf['Fecha'], thisdf['count'], 'o-', label=country)


ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

And here is the result (for a minimal version of your input file):
[image: example plot]